# System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60))

Tags: apex, httprequest

I am trying to connect another org using user agent auth flow, I am getting auth code and passing it to apex method and then I am getting the below error.

```
private static final string RESOURCE_REDIRECT_URI = 'https://xxxx.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/Connected_Orgs';
    private static final string RESOURCE_CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXX';
    private static final string RESOURCE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXX';
public Static String getAccesstoken(String Accesscode){         

         Accesscode = Accesscode.replace('=','%3D').trim();        
         Accesscode = Accesscode.replace('"', '');

         String loginUri = 'https://test.salesforce.com';
         String header = '';
         String reqbody =  'grant_type=authorization_code';
                reqbody += '&client_id='+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(RESOURCE_CLIENT_ID, 'UTF-8');
                reqbody += '&client_secret='+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(RESOURCE_CLIENT_SECRET, 'UTF-8');
                reqbody += '&code='+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(Accesscode, 'UTF-8');
                reqbody += '&redirect_uri='+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(RESOURCE_REDIRECT_URI, 'UTF-8');
                reqbody += '&scope=refresh_token full';

         String endpoint = loginUri + '/services/oauth2/token?' + reqbody;   

         Map<String, object> mapReqBody = getHTTPResponse(endpoint, header, 'POST');

        header = 'access_token:'+string.valueOf(mapReqBody.get('access_token')) + ' ' + 'refresh_token:'+string.valueOf(mapReqBody.get('refresh_token'));        
        return header;        
    }

    public static Map<String, object> getHTTPResponse(String endpoint, String header, String method){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();  
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);        

        if(header != ''){
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setHeader('Authorization', header);
        }
        Http httpReq = new Http();  
        HTTPResponse res = httpReq.send(req);

        return (Map<String, object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    }
```

> ```
> https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?
> grant_type=authorization_code&
> client_id=xxxx&
> client_secret=xxxx&
> code=aPrxvJxdfdfsdcv_QO04.ORKytXPF4gEknyrN6HU5N24pQAfFXcxSTKuMz3uTziP_8Cug%3D%3D&
> redirect_uri=https://xxxx.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/Connected_Orgs?0.source=alohaHeader&
> scope=refresh_token full
> ```

**Error:*

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected
>   a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or
>   'null') at input location [1,2]

**Actual Response body:**

```
response: System.HttpResponse[Status=Unknown Version, StatusCode=400] 
response Body: <h1>Bad Message 400</h1><pre>reason: Unknown Version</pre> 
response status: Unknown Version
```

Comment: Likely it means that the endpoint is returning to you HTML rather than JSON. You should try to debug the actual response body and wrap your deserialization in a try catch. Given the level of information in your post, it will be nearly impossible to help more than that until you add that information.

Comment: added what I am getting in the response, Response, body, and status.

Comment: it worked after removing this "reqbody += '&scope=refresh_token full';

Answer (score 0):

it worked after removing this "reqbody += '&scope=refresh_token full';